# Shared Preference Swift 4- iOS- Unique Alamofire user id

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, xcode9

In my classifieds project  there is a user registration page and user id generated in php  so  in that particular user id all other data of particular user need to save. I would share my swift codes for registration and  swift data form to save in that particular user id. But registration user id is getting saved successfully but the datas entering in data form is not saving in unique user id. Please help me in fix that...

Registration page swift

```
 let parameters: Parameters=[

        "user_name":nameTextField.text!,
        "user_email":emailTextField.text!,
        "user_mobile":mobileNumb.text!,
        "password":passwordTextField.text!
    ]
          //Sending http post request
    Alamofire.request("https://alot.ae/api/user_reg.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
        {
            response in
            //printing response
            print(response)

            //getting the json value from the server
            if let result = response.result.value {

                //converting it as NSDictionary
                let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

                let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                //This class variable needs to be defined every class where you set or fetch values from NSUserDefaults
                defaults.setValue("password", forKey: "user_id")
                defaults.synchronize()
                //Call this when you're done editing the defaults. It saves you

            }}
```

And my swift code for other form which have to save data in that particular user id

```
 //creating parameters for the post request
    let parameters: Parameters=[

        "full_name":profN.text!,
        "position":position.text!,
        "email":emailCompa.text!,
        "phone_number":numComP.text!

    ]
    //Sending http post request
    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_EMPLOYER_PROFILE, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
        {
            response in
            //printing response
            print(response)

            //getting the json value from the server
            if let result = response.result.value {

                //converting it as NSDictionary
                let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set("URL_USER_EMPLOYER_PROFILE", forKey: "user")

            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your requirement?

Comment: i have created random user id for registration. For example a user with email: abc@...com and password: xxxx registered. So i got confirmed that used id : ABCD have been created. So this same user whenever login in and fill form like education details or any datas  have to save in same user id: ABCD. like wise.  How can i do this? please let me know (mean shared preference stored datas in same user id for one user)

Comment: @AzeTech And how would you handle when user will change his device?

Comment: @ TheTiger , doesn't matter user changes device what i mean is suppose if i am new user i will register so there will be user id. So whenever i add my details or upload any files that have to be saved in that particular user id. Suppose some other person is registering that user will also have separate userid. Then all details have to enter in that particular user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with iPhone developer @ Muhammed Azharuddin, by creating a class for user defaults to store datas in user_id

```
extension UserDefaults{

    static let isLoggedIn = "com.xyz.AlotTest1isLoggedIn"
    static let userId = "com.xyz.AlotTest1userId"

}
```

And call this extension in parameters after @IBAction

```
//creating parameters for the post request
        let parameters: Parameters=[

            "full_name":profN.text!,
            "position":position.text!,
            "email":emailCompa.text!,
            "phone_number":numComP.text!,
             "user_id" : AuthService.instance.userId ?? ""
        ]


       // Sending http post request
       Alamofire.request(URL_USER_EMPLOYER_PROFILE, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
            {
                response in
              //  printing response
                print(response)

        //    getting the json value from the server
               if let result = response.result.value {
                   UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user_id")
                 //  converting it as NSDictionary
                   let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

                let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

                //This class variable needs to be defined every class where you set or fetch values from NSUserDefaults

                                               }
       }


        let employer = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "employer") as! EmployerViewController

        self.present(employer, animated: true)
      }
```